# Typescript, generic function probably return callback function

Tags: typescript, callback, typescript-generics

is started 3th day on my stack overflow in my mind, so is a minimal example from what i want to do, look at comments and please help me,
as i understood the ReturnType looks like any here, and i cant override the return type in case when it probably will be callback function

```
type Test = <T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(
  ...args: Parameters<T>
) => ((bar: string) => any) | ReturnType<T>;

const q: Test = () => 1; // TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T> | ((bar: string) => any)'
const w: Test = () => (bar) => bar;
```

Comment: You need to explain what cases are desired failures vs undesired failures.  I do not understand what the goal is here.   `q` SHOULD be an error.  The only possible return types for a `Test` are a function `(bar: string) => any` and `void`.  `ReturnType<T>` is always `void` since `T extends (...args: any[]) => void`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste i need to return any, not only void, and return predefined function with predefined argumenst, somethink like that


`type callback = <T extends (...args: Parameters<any>) => ReturnType<any>>(
  ...args: Parameters<T>`
`) => (b: number) => any;`
`export function pickCard(x: callback): any;`
`export function pickCard(x: any): any;`
`export function pickCard(x: Function) {`
`  if (typeof x === 'function') {`
`    return x('');`
`  }`
`  return x;`
`}`
`pickCard(() => 'a');`
`pickCard(() => (a) => a);`

Comment: Ok so in your `pickCard` example, there is some type which we expect for `pickCard` to return which here seems to be a `string`.  We want to be able to accept an argument for `pickCard` which is either a `string` or a function that returns a `string`.  Some of these generics need to be known in advance in order to be at all useful.  How is this? https://tsplay.dev/WYJJgw

Comment: @LindaPaiste your example looks good, but the main idea it should be one type or interface and one function

Comment: expected result
pickCard(() => 'a');
pickCard(() => (callback: ((bar: string) => any) => callback(bar: string);